# When non-linear transformation on a subset becomes on a linear one on the whole set?

Tags: linear-transformations, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am watching a series of Lectures by N.Arkani-Hamed on the `Positive Geometry of the Real World`. And in the second lecture he gives a crash course on the projective geometry and considers some examples of advanteges in working in projective way.

Conformal (Moebius)  transformations of $\mathbb{C}$ are given by:
$$
z \rightarrow\frac{az+b}{cz + d}
$$
Which from the point of view of variable $z$ is a *nonlinear* transformation. But in projective space $\begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix} \sim \lambda \begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix}$, the transformations becomes a linear one:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow M \begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Where $M$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix. And this approach can be extended to higher dimensions, where are non-linear transformation in inhomogeneous coordinates becomes a linear one in projective space.

Inhomogeneous coordinates are a subspace in the whole projective space, by
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ z \end{pmatrix}
$$
One covers all the projective space, except one point.

My question is - are there other examples or classes of cases, when a non-linear or complicated transformation on a certain subset/subspace becomes a simple one on some extension of it?

Comment: The projective space is not a subset of $\mathbb{C}$.  Rather, it is a 1-dimensional vector space built out of a partition of $\mathbb{C}$ whose equivalence classes form the vectors.  There are various uninteresting ways to achieve the same phenomenon.  For instance consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x,y)=(x,y^2)$.  This is a nonlinear function, but it generates a linear function in the first coordinate, for instance by identifying $(x,y_1)\sim(x,y_2)$.